# Qt state machines: more transition attempts than expected

Tags: c++, qt, state-machine

I have created a simplified example of a state machine transitioning between 2 states on a button click (+ a checkbox showing the active state). I am seeing more calls to the transitions'`eventTest` method than I expect.

```
#include <QtStateMachine/QStateMachine>
#include <QtStateMachine/QSignalTransition>

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QCheckBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>


class MySignalTransition : public QSignalTransition
{
public:
    MySignalTransition(QString name, QPushButton* button, QCheckBox* checkBox) :
        QSignalTransition(button, &QAbstractButton::clicked),
        cb(checkBox)
    {
        setObjectName(name);
    }
protected:
    bool eventTest(QEvent* e) override {
        qDebug() << objectName() << "tested on" << e->type() << '|' << cb->isChecked();
        return QSignalTransition::eventTest(e);
    }
private:
    QCheckBox* cb;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);


    QWidget w;
    w.setFixedSize(200, 200);
    QPushButton button(QStringLiteral("Click me"), &w);
    QCheckBox checkbox(&w);
    button.move(10, 80);
    checkbox.move(10, 20);

    QStateMachine m;
    QState s1, s2;
    m.addState(&s1);
    m.addState(&s2);
    m.setInitialState(&s1);

    s1.assignProperty(&checkbox, "checked", false);
    s2.assignProperty(&checkbox, "checked", true);

    //button will be used to make the transition back and forth between states s1 and s2
    MySignalTransition t1("Transition 1", &button, &checkbox), t2("Transition 2", &button, &checkbox);
    t1.setTargetState(&s2);
    t2.setTargetState(&s1);

    s1.addTransition(&t1);
    s2.addTransition(&t2);

    w.show();
    m.start();
    return app.exec();
}
```

On top of the checkbox, I placed a `qDebug() << ...` to watch when Qt attempts to perform transitions.
The first attempt is right when the state machine starts, before I do any click on the button. I guess (but I am not sure) that this is expected.

The real problem happens when I actually do click on the button. I see:

1. `eventTest` is called from the **starting** state (`event->type() == QEvent::None`)
2. `eventTest` is called from the **starting** state (`event->type() == QEvent::StateMachineSignal`)
3. `eventTest` is called from the **target** state (`event->type() == QEvent::None`)

The one call I am most surprised about is point 1.

- What causes the state machine to try the transition again when I click on the button with `QEvent::None`? This is especially surprising to me because it is always a transition the state machine has already tried (either on start or on the previous click).
- If I were to create another transition out of `s1` and/or `s2`, should I be worried that transition could have a higher priority than my signal transitions without any way for me to control it?

---

**Edit**
To address @Scheff's cat comment below, I changed the transition class to be:

```
class MySignalTransition : public QSignalTransition
{
public:
    MySignalTransition(QString name, QPushButton* button, QCheckBox* checkBox) :
        QSignalTransition(button, &QAbstractButton::clicked),
        cb(checkBox)
    {
        setObjectName(name);
    }
protected:
    bool event(QEvent* e) override {
        return false;
    }
    bool eventTest(QEvent* e) override {
        qDebug() << objectName() << "tested on" << e->type() << '|' << cb->isChecked();
        return transition;
    }
private:
    QCheckBox* cb;
public:
    inline static bool transition = false;
};
```

and right after creating the push button, added:

```
QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, []() { MySignalTransition::transition = true; });
```

By doing that, the state machine lets me do 1 click before it starts an infinite loop.
When clicking, `MySignalTransition::transition` is set to true, then `eventTest` is called.
With a breakpoint, it is easy to see `eventTest` is never called with `event->type() == QEvent::StateMachineSignal`.

To me, this is a clear indication there is more to it than just probing.

- First, it would need to do the probing with the actual event, not with a dummy event.
- Second, it would not do the transition if the result of the probing was correct, I still should see the 2nd call to `eventTest`.
- Last, I thought maybe the state machine tries to execute as many transitions as it can and will then pass the click signal to whatever other state it lands on.
  However, I am not very satisfied by that explanation because the attempt to execute an automatic transition is already done when entering the state (it is the third call to `eventTest`) and because I think my click should be applied on the state that is active at the very moment I do it, not on just "whatever other state it lands on".

Comment: According to doc. [QSignalTransition::eventTest()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsignaltransition.html#eventTest) _returns true if the event is a QStateMachine::SignalEvent object and the event's sender and signal index match this transition, and returns false otherwise._ Hence, I assume what you see is some kind of probing (before filtering). Did you try to overload `event()` instead of `eventTest()`?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Overriding `QObject::event(QEvent*)`, if that is what you mean, has no effect. It seems it is never called. Why would it BTW? the guard is in `eventTest` already.

Comment: About the probing, I think this is not it. Firstly, what would be a reason to call `eventTest` once for probing, then once more for real, let alone with an incorrect event type (`QEvent::None` instead of `QEvent::StateMachineSignal`) on the first call. Secondly, replacing `return QSignalTransition::eventTest(e)` by `return true`, causes the state machine to starts an infinite loop of switching the states all by itself. It is to be expected since it removes any actual guard; my point though is that the first call on `eventTest` does more than just "probing", it makes the state machine execute.

Comment: Concerning `QSignalTransition::event()`, you're correct. - I just had a look onto source code: https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/statemachine/qsignaltransition.cpp.html#246